# Exceptional levels of kernel spam about "MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware"

Tags: drivers, kernel

```
Jul  1 22:17:14 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.484038] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.516031] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.548076] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.580026] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.612047] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.644054] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.676055] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.708081] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.740061] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Jul  1 22:17:15 nosgoth kernel: [1382019.772074] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
```

As you can see, it's spamming tens of times a second, probably 20 or 30, and only a reboot seems to fix it. A reboot is kind of expensive as it's a dom0. This wasn't a problem when I was running an archlinux kernel, but seems to be a problem with whatever kernel ubuntu is using.

is there any solution to this? I cannot find anything on the internet except for the driver source code when I look for it.

The Megaraid SAS device:

```
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 1078 (rev 04)
```

I'm not sure what else is useful, it's a Dell Poweredge 2900 server, with SATA drives attached.

The server is operating fine, just the kernel is being ridiculously spammy to the log.

EDIT: "Language", said Captain America.

Answer (score 1):

This is still ongoing, and was recently patched for RedHat related to 2 CVEs:
(Clarity): This issue was not related to the CVEs, rather, the patch was aimed at 2 CVE's + this and a couple bug fixes.

https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016-2006.html

(edit)   which appears to point back to this: https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/8/18/553

(edit)   I'm in the middle of recompiling+testing the kernel, I'll host it in a few with the patch.

```
Oct 31 21:38:36 ohlookadell kernel: [943983.390883] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Oct 31 21:38:36 ohlookadell kernel: [943983.414877] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Oct 31 21:38:36 ohlookadell kernel: [943983.438801] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Oct 31 21:38:36 ohlookadell kernel: [943983.462982] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
Oct 31 21:38:36 ohlookadell kernel: [943983.486832] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY failed/not supported by firmware
```

Answer (score 0):

This is emitted from the driver in function megasas_get_pd_list(), see drivers/scsi/megaraid/megaraid_sas_base.c

```
    if (instance->ctrl_context && !instance->mask_interrupts)
            ret = megasas_issue_blocked_cmd(instance, cmd,
                    MFI_IO_TIMEOUT_SECS);
    else
            ret = megasas_issue_polled(instance, cmd);

    switch (ret) {
    case DCMD_FAILED:
            dev_info(&instance->pdev->dev, "MR_DCMD_PD_LIST_QUERY "
                    "failed/not supported by firmware\n");

            if (instance->ctrl_context)
                    megaraid_sas_kill_hba(instance);
            else
                    instance->pd_list_not_supported = 1;
            break;
```

....

I wonder if changing the driver kernel parameter msix_disable to 1 will change the behavior.

Comment: Do you know what `msix_disable` will do?